# Extract a particular field in '\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\' format in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

So my string looks likes this:

`"\177\260\002\377\004\210\005\001ABC 01\000\000\000\000\000\00074
0-053352\000\0001GD14222393\000\000\r\013\007\336\000\000\377\377\377\377\377\37
7\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\001CMUPACSDBHBBU-HHW-AC-BFG\000\
000\000\000\000\000\000A00\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\177\000\000\0
00\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"`

I want to extract `00074 0-053352` and `001CMUPACSDBHBBU-HHW-AC-BFG` and I was wondering if there is any sophisticated way to do this?

Comment: Why those substrings?  How should your extraction code determine what to extract?

Comment: My extraction is based on the byte number. For e.g. 9th byte has ID

Comment: Do you know how long the field is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sequences = [part for part in mystring.split("\\") if not part.isdigit()]
```

?

Comment: This one worked as the fields I'm extracting are not pure numbers. Thanks for pointing out and sorry for my bad.